# Bootstrap v3 - DateTime Picker - set Value on iOS not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using a bootstrap v3 [datetime picker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) in a hybrid app. There is a **label** which shows date and time values in the app. So whenever user `clicks on the label` it should show a datetime picker to select a date and time. I have implemented it and is working well.

Now when the picker pops up then I can set a date & time value to show when the picker poped up on screen.

```
$('#MetngSumryEditStartDateTime').data("DateTimePicker").date( moment( _defaultStDateTime ).format('Do MMMM YYYY, h:mm a') );
```

Remember as the **picker is required to have an input** field to operate on. So when I provide a text field to it then on devices, the **soft keyboard appears**! which is really now required in my case because user is not allowed to type in the text field and instead a label is there to show the values of date & time.

For this I've given it a **checkbox** as input field. Now pickers works well on `Android devices` and desktop `browsers` like `chrome` but on **iOS it is not working**.

Here is complete list of code.

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div id='meetingSumDateTimeEndArea'> 
            <span class='start'>End</span> 
            <span class='time' id='meetingSumEndTime'>" + (UserProfile.getUserProfileDetails().MeetingEndTime[i]) + "</span>" 
            <span class='date' id='meetingSumEndDate'>" + UserProfile.getUserProfileDetails().MeetingEndDate[i] + "</span>"     
          </div>

          <input type='checkbox'   id='MetngSumryEditEndDateTime'  />   

      </div>
   </div>

     <script type='text/javascript'> 
          $(function() {                  
                    var _defaultStTime ='9:00 pm'; // hardcoded for testing purpose
                    var _defaultStDate ='29 Mar, 2015'; // hardcoded for testing purpose

                    var _defaultStDateTime = _defaultStDate + ' ' + _defaultStTime  ;                   
                    console.log('_defaultStDateTime=' + _defaultStDateTime  ) ; 

                    $('#meetingSumDateTimeEndArea').on('click', function(e){  
                        $('#MetngSumryEditEndDateTime').focus();  
                    });

                    $('#MetngSumryEditEndDateTime').datetimepicker( { format:'Do MMMM YYYY, h:mm a' , sideBySide: true , defaultDate: _defaultStDateTime } );                                                               
                    $('#MetngSumryEditEndDateTime').datetimepicker().on('dp.change',function(e) {  

                         $('#MetngSumryEditEndDateTime').data("DateTimePicker").date( moment( _defaultStDateTime ).format('Do MMMM YYYY, h:mm a') );    

                        console.log( e.date.format('DD MMM, YYYY')  );  

                        var tm = e.date.format('hh:mm a').split(' ');  
                        console.log( tm[0] + " " + tm[1] );                     

                        console.log( e.date.format('hh:mm a')  );   

                    }); 

            }); 

    </script>
```

**Update**

I tried below suggested **v4.13.28** and set **`focusOnShow: false`** but still keyboard pops up. I tried this with text field.

Now I reverted back to `checkbox` field in order to prevent the soft keyboard but problem is on iOS.

I give it an **initial date and time** value, so when a picker opens up on iOS device then `first time it shows the current time` and if you change to another time and close the picker and reopen it again then it shows correct last modified time. However in case of **date**, it shows correct supplied date whenever it opens.

So it is good to handle date but has bug in time value settings for the very first time only.

**How I fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

Version `4.13.28` (currently in the [dev branch](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/tree/development)) introduces [`focusOnShow`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#focusonshow).

When set to `false` the text box input will not get focus, which should prevent the keyboard from displaying on mobile devices

Comment: Today I got chance to try this version. But it still gives same issue. Please suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

After long efforts, I found the issue.

**The issue is with the JavaScript Date object implementation on Safari (iOS).**

The **datetimepicker** component uses **moment** for date/time manipulation and *moment is depending on the under-laying platform's date/time implementation*.

Now when I use below code to **extract the Time** information.

```
moment("1999-01-01 11:00 am").format("HH:mm:ss");
```

This gives correct time information on Android & Windows tablets. **But this fails to recognize on iOS...says..... Invalid Date.**

Now to dig it further down, If I give same value to a **JavaScript Date** object

```
new Date("1999-01-01 11:00 am");
```

Again this converts it correctly on Android & Windows devices, **but fails on iOS....says.... Invalid Date.**

This means Date Object implementation is broken or having issues on iOS.

**To fix my issue:**

I provided another parameter to the moment in order to extract Time data only.

```
moment("1999-01-01 11:00 am" , ['h:mm a'] ).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

Now this works fine everywhere.

Note: the `1999-01-01 11:00 am` are hard-coded for the sake of this question, though they come dynamically in the app.